# How to retrieve django db info

Tags: django, database, object, models

I'm introducing django. I've created a model with two fields: Clientes and Equipos.

I wanna print but with my own format, so I would like to have a list or better a dict for it.

But I don't know what "example = models.object.values()" do. I don't know if example is a list, dictionary...

I've tried with models.object.get() but it doesn't work.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Acutally, example is an instance of `django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet`, not just a simple list, it's a queryset

Because of `example` is a query set, you can use query set method, do whatever you want.The [django queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/) document is helpful.

you can traverse `example` variable like this:

```
for item in example:
  do_what_you_want(item)
```

As you declare in you model, your example may like this:

```
example = [  
             {'Clients':'clients data','Equipos':'equipos data'},
             {'Clients':'clients data','Equipos':'equipos data'}
          ]
```

I don't recommend you to convert your `example` to `list` type, if you do this, you can not use the powerfull django query set method.Django queryset method is more powerful than a python native list.

Comment: well, I understand.
So if I want to print my django query 

do_what_you_want should be print item directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
example = models.object.values()
```

`example` will be a kind of iterator of dicts where keys are the field names of a model.  To make it a list of dicts just do:

```
example = list(models.object.values())
```

So `example` will look something like this:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'Clientes': 'some clientes', 'Equipos': 'some equipos'},
    {'id': 2, 'Clientes': 'anoter clientes', 'Equipos': 'another equipos'}
]
```

Comment: I understand, thanks
but what happens if I would have more than 2 fields ? I mean...

`
example = models.object.values(Clientes,Equipos,AnotherField,AnotherField)
`
what is the key in that case?

I've another issue. I got it, but when I print it there is an extra char "u" before my key. Look,

[(u'test22', 4), (u'test', 4)]

and it should be 'test22',4 ...

Comment: Of course the additional keys will be added to the dicts. `{..., 'AnotherField': 'some'}`.  And I forgot to mention that the `id` field will be in the dict too.

Comment: Extra `u` char before the string means that the string is in unicode: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: thanks catavaran, wow!
I've just another question... I'm trying to get the values of one Client. I'm doing this:
`